# Regex permutations without repetition

Tags: regex, permutation

I need a RegEx to check if I can find a expression in a string.

For the string "abc" I would like to match the first appearance of any of the permutations without repetition, in this case 6: abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba.

For example, in this string "adesfecabefgswaswabdcbaes" it'd find a coincidence in the position 7.

Also I'd need the same for permutations without repetition like this "abbc". The cases for this are 12: acbb, abcb, abbc, cabb, cbab, cbba, bacb, babc, bcab, bcba, bbac, bbca

For example, in this string "adbbcacssesfecabefgswaswabdcbaes" it'd find a coincidence in the position 3.

Also, I would like to know how would that be for similar cases.

EDIT
I'm not looking for the combinations of the permutations, no. I already have those. WHat I'm looking for is a way to check if any of those permutations is in a given string.

EDIT 2
This regex I think covers my first question
([abc])(?!\1)([abc])(?!\2|\1)[abc]

Can find all permutations(6) of "abc" in any secuence of characters.

Now I need to do the same when I have a repeated character like abbc (12 combinations).

Comment: Permutations of an infinite set without repetitions are not a regular language. Regex is the wrong tool.

Comment: there's no regex operator to represent "permutations of a string". you'll have to calculate them to build that regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already have a program that create all the permutations, in fact I do have those combinations. What I need is to have to check if any of those combinations are in more that 2 million strings, I need to check the coincidences...that's the reason I thought regex could be a good solution

Comment: To the reopen voters: Regex is a bad solution for this problem. The problem has been solved in a better way in the duplicate question.

Comment: When you have to check more than 5 million combinations to see if you can match any of the 6, 12 or 400 permutations I can tell you regex is the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
([abc])(?!\1)([abc])(?!\2|\1)[abc]
```

You can use this without `g` flag to get the position.See demo.The position of first group is what you want.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/41

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/42

Comment: This cannot be generalized.. and it fails for `[abbc]`

Comment: It fails for `aba` now.

Comment: @vks I meant OP's second case.. :P

Comment: @vks either you should read the question again.. or I should.. and I just did :P

Comment: @karthikmanchala will wait for OP to clarify.......m confused now

Comment: @vks it is simple.. you did it for `abc`.. and you can do similarly for `abcd`.. what if it is `abbc`?..

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you might "need a regex" is if you are working with a library or tool which only permits specifying certain kinds of rules with a regex. For instance, some editors can be customized to color certain syntactic constructs in a particular way, and they only allow those constructs to be specified as regular expressions.

Otherwise, you don't "need a regex", you "need a program". Here's one:

```
// are two arrays equal?
function array_equal(a1, a2) {
  return a1.every(function(chr, i) { return chr === a2[i]; });
}

// are two strings permutations of each other?
function is_permutation(s1, s2) {
  return array_equal(s1.split('').sort(), s2.split('').sort());
}

// make a function which finds permutations in a string
function make_permutation_finder(chars) {
  var len = chars.length;
  return function(str) {
    for (i = 0; i < str.length - len; i++) {
      if (is_permutation(chars, str.slice(i, i+len))) return i;
    }
    return -1; 
  };
}

> finder = make_permutation_finder("abc");
> console.log(finder("adesfecabefgswaswabdcbaes"));
< 6
```

Regexps are far from being powerful enough to do this kind of thing.

However, there is an alternative, which is precompute the permutations and build a dynamic regexp to find them. You did not provide a language tag, but here's an example in JS. Assuming you have the permutations and don't have to worry about escaping special regexp characters, that's just

```
regexp = new RegExp(permuations.join('|'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already have a program that create all the permutations, in fact I do have those combinations. What I need is to have to check if any of those combinations are in more that 2 million strings, I need to check the coincidences...that's the reason I thought regex could be a good solution