# Regex blocks of permutations

Tags: c#, regex

Thanks to Kobi I just resolve the problem of checking all the permutations without repetition for a given string "abbc". This is the solution

```
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){4}(?<-A>)(?<-B>){2}(?<-C>)
```

The expression has to have one "a", two "b" and one "c" in 4 consecutive characters.

Now I need something more complicated, I need to check a expression with 2 blocks of permutations:

1. In the first 6 positions it has to find all the permutations of "abccc" but adding to each one a character in the 3rd position that can be any of them (a, b or c).
2. In the second block  it has to find all the permutations of "abccc"

I don't know if I have explained myself well, but:

1. For the first 6 positions it has to have one a, one b, 3 c and in the 3rd position any value (a,b or c) no matter the order except for the 3rd position that can be any
2. For the next 5 positions it has to have one a, one b and 3 c no matter the order.

I'm trying to explain it the best way possible. I'm sorry it looked like a copy-paste which is not.

The regex I'm looking for is "abXccc-abccc" where X could be a,  b or c and the - separate the 2 blocks, although they are together I'm adding the - because for the first 6 characters I have to look for all the combinations and for the last 5 the same.

It doesn't have to be this way, it could be something similar, this is just an example. It could be "aabXXcc-abbc" for example.

Comment: You may want to provide your attempt so far. Right now, this sounds like a copy-pasted homework assignment that you expect others to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I made a program to calculate all the combinations of the no repetition permutations and I compared one by one, the times were so high with 900 millions iterations, that's the reason I'm trying to figure out how to do it with regex. This way I only have to do 2 millions iterations. I'm new using regex and I don't know how to start...

Comment: I've added answer, I hope it explains how to combine these blocks. I realize you may not want the dash there but you can simple remove it. You should have no problem combining different groups, like `aabXXcc-abbc`, using this approach. By the way - you are in luck you are using .Net - other regex flavors do not have this feature, and I think this solution is (relatively) simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple to adapt [the previous pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30751500/7586) to the new one.

The second block is straightforward:

```
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){5}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}
```

Next, the only thing you need to know is that you can specify the same group more than once. This is explained in [Martin Büttner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/7586), which I've linked before.

So, the first block, with `[abc]` on the first position, can be written as:

```
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){2}[abc](?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}
```

Combined:

```
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){2}[abc](?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){3}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}-(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){5}(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}
```

Or, with the Ignore Whitespace flag:

```
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){2}  # Match 2 a, b, or c's
[abc]                           # Match a, b, or c, but don't push to stack.
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){3}  # Match 3 a, b, or c's
(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}        # Check we've matched 1 a, 1 b and 3 c's.
-                               # match the dash
(?:(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)|(?<C>c)){5}  # Match 5 a, b, or c's
(?<-A>)(?<-B>)(?<-C>){3}        # Check we've matched 1 a, 1 b and 3 c's.
```

This is not as elegant (it has some repetition), but should still be simple to understand as a next step of the previous question.

[Working example at Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3CA%3Ea)%7C(%3F%3CB%3Eb)%7C(%3F%3CC%3Ec))%7B2%7D%20%20%23%20Match%202%20a%2C%20b%2C%20or%20c%27s%0D%0A%5Babc%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Match%20a%2C%20b%2C%20or%20c%2C%20but%20don%27t%20push%20to%20stack.%0D%0A(%3F%3A(%3F%3CA%3Ea)%7C(%3F%3CB%3Eb)%7C(%3F%3CC%3Ec))%7B3%7D%20%20%23%20Match%203%20a%2C%20b%2C%20or%20c%27s%0D%0A(%3F%3C-A%3E)(%3F%3C-B%3E)(%3F%3C-C%3E)%7B3%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Check%20we%27ve%20matched%201%20a%2C%201%20b%20and%203%20c%27s.%0D%0A-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20match%20the%20dash%0D%0A(%3F%3A(%3F%3CA%3Ea)%7C(%3F%3CB%3Eb)%7C(%3F%3CC%3Ec))%7B5%7D%20%20%23%20Match%205%20a%2C%20b%2C%20or%20c%27s%0D%0A(%3F%3C-A%3E)(%3F%3C-B%3E)(%3F%3C-C%3E)%7B3%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Check%20we%27ve%20matched%201%20a%2C%201%20b%20and%203%20c%27s.&i=abaccc-abccc%0D%0Aabaccc-ccabc%0D%0Accacca-ccbba&o=x)